# Is there a reason why extension methods can't be invoked directly on "this"?

Tags: c#, syntax, extension-methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can you not invoke extension methods directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906170/why-can-you-not-invoke-extension-methods-directly)

Lets assume the following code:

```
 public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void SayHello(this Foo self)
    {}
}

public class Foo
{
    this.SayHello(); //this works
    SayHello(); //this does not compile
}
```

I'm just interested in the reasoning behind this, why can't extension methods be invoked on an implicit `this` ?

`this.SayHello()` and `SayHello` means the same thing when applied to instance methods.
So why use different behavior when calling extension methods?

Comment: Because they are not really extension methods but compiler magic for static function calls

Comment: `SayHello( this )` should compile. The method has one parameter, you can't just invoke it with no parameters.

Comment: @Esailija , the same compiler magic could easily have been applied on an implicit this..

Comment: Ok, so it's a duplicate, but the answer is sort of nonsense there IMO. rambling about private vars and IL code... this is a parser/compiler issue only...

Comment: I don't think we can give a satisfactory answer. There are probably no technical reasons why this couldn't work. The cop-out answer is "it was specified that way". But only the C# team knows why they specified it that way.

Comment: @RogerAlsing Yeah now that I think about it, it should be technically possible

Comment: @Jon pretty sure I remember an Eric answer to this that is basically the classic "because that is what we chose"

Comment: @MarcGravell What a let down :) I was hoping for some deeper reason behind it, oh well.

Comment: Turn it around - would it really lead to better code? Calling it on yourself is kind of odd already.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It would be sort of nice for internal DSL's applied to marker interfaces for example. just my 2 cents

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yes, that's what I'd expect: the cost is greater than the benefit.

Comment: @JonSkeet: In fact, Eric said so in a comment to your answer to a very similar question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772148/how-to-call-an-extension-method-from-own-class-without-casting